# How do I configure SE Linux so PHP can connect to Postgres by socket

Tags: php, php-fpm, postgresql, selinux, rocky-linux

I have a PHP application that connects to a Postgresql Database.
This works when I connect via network but I get an SELinux violation when trying to connect using the socket. I believe the contexts are set correctly and the correct flags are enabled.

```
httpd_can_network_connect --> on
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> on
```

the sealert message for the failure looks like this:

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/php-fpm from connectto access on the unix_stream_socket /run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that php-fpm should be allowed connectto access on the .s.PGSQL.5432 unix_stream_socket by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'php-fpm' --raw | audit2allow -M my-phpfpm
# semodule -X 300 -i my-phpfpm.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0
Target Objects                /run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 [ unix_stream_socket
                              ]
Source                        php-fpm
Source Path                   /usr/sbin/php-fpm
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          localhost.localdomain
Source RPM Packages           php-fpm-8.2.13-1.el9.remi.x86_64
Target RPM Packages
SELinux Policy RPM            selinux-policy-targeted-38.1.23-1.el9.noarch
Local Policy RPM              selinux-policy-targeted-38.1.23-1.el9.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Host Name                     localhost.localdomain
Platform                      Linux localhost.localdomain
                              5.14.0-362.8.1.el9_3.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC
                              Wed Nov 8 17:36:32 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   1080
First Seen                    2023-12-29 14:34:45 PST
Last Seen                     2024-01-31 12:15:18 PST
Local ID                      e3bcfa07-6867-47e3-bedf-4d8ca2d16443

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1706732118.737:4455): avc:  denied  { connectto } for  pid=516281 comm="php-fpm" path="/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0


type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1706732118.737:4455): arch=x86_64 syscall=connect success=no exit=EACCES a0=8 a1=561638666d58 a2=6e a3=7fa9f9d951a0 items=0 ppid=516267 pid=516281 auid=4294967295 uid=984 gid=984 euid=984 suid=984 fsuid=984 egid=984 sgid=984 fsgid=984 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=php-fpm exe=/usr/sbin/php-fpm subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)

Hash: php-fpm,httpd_t,unconfined_service_t,unix_stream_socket,connectto
```

One thing that looks odd is the lack of an RPM package for the postgres socket.

There are instructions provided to generate a local policy module; but I don't understand exactly what those commands will do and hesitate to just run them.

```
ausearch -c 'php-fpm' --raw | audit2allow -M my-phpfpm
semodule -X 300 -i my-phpfpm.pp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These commands create a selinux policy. `ausearch` scans the audit logs to find what PHP wanted to do and `audit2allow` creates a policy that permits whatever the first command found. Then `semodule` activates the newly created policy.

I suggest to add `-a 4455` key to the `ausearch` command for it to only permit whatever was forbidden during this particular event. That would be safer, since it won't accidenally permit anything unrelated:

```
ausearch -a 4455 --raw | audit2allow -M my-phpfpm-pg5432
semodule -X 300 -i my-php-pg5432.pp
```

Notice also I named the policy slightly differently, because with this filter we know for sure what exactly it permits.

See [`man ausearch`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ausearch.8.html) and [`man audit2allow`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/audit2allow) and [`man semodule`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/semodule.8.html) for details.

---

There could be no package for the socket file. A socket is a dynamic filesystem object, which is created and removed on the fly. Think it's a "temporary file" which is only valid while the service that created it is running. For that reason, sockets are usually created in a non-volatile in-memory file system, mounted as `/run`, which doesn't persist during reboot.

What is really strange is that the socket's selinux type is `unconfined_service_t`. There should have been a predefined type for the Postgres socket and a policy which would allow `httd_t` processes to access it. I think it's sensible to file the feature request for this to be implemented.

Comment: It might be noteworthy that when connecting via sockets the options `httpd_can_network_connect` and `httpd_can_network_connect_db` should not be needed anymore.

Comment: Looking at older version of postgres on another machine the context is `postgresql_var_run_t`. After running the generated policy module the socket had the context changed to `postgresql_var_run_t` so that is probably what it is supposed to be.
Postgresql 16 isn't part of the main package repo for Rocky 9 yet; I had to install the repository RPM for it. Maybe that's why the context isn't set?

Comment: Definitely that is the cause. You can try to extract SELinux related things from the native package, audit it and include it into your current system, that would be the clearest solution. And file a feature request to whoever created that repository ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here appears to be that you're running `php-fpm` as an `unconfined_service_t` service. How did you start the service?

If you are starting it via `systemd` I'd suggest running a relabel on the packages as something isn't marked right. `php-fpm` on my system comes up as `httpd_t` and as such a bunch of rules already running for the service should apply and work for you.

```
fixfiles -R $(rpm -qa | grep php | paste -sd,) restore
```

Should relabel all the PHP packages correctly. Then restart `php-fpm` via `systemctl` as per normal.

Comment: Php-fpm was started with systemd. Near as I can tell php-fpm is running with context `httpd_t`. Maybe I'm misreading the report but I think php-fpm would be the Source Context with `httpd_t` and the postgres socket would be the Target Context with `unconfined_service_t`